# Python assign "\" to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I wanted to know if it was possible to assign "\" to a variable in python? If so, how?

I think the anti slash is complicated to use. I can't find anything on the internet for "\".

Comment: Just use two after each other, \\.

Comment: just for reference, this is called `escaping a character`. A proper IDE would higlight stuff like this

Comment: ```"\\"``` evaluates to a string containing one backslash.